# Plot interaction effect in sem model with observed variables in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am estimating an SEM model that has observed variables. I am using SEM to handle missing data using FIML. My model has an interaction term to test for moderation. Here is a toy example that illustrates the issue.

```
library(lavaan)
library(car)
library(dplyr)

data(starwars)

sw2 <- starwars %>% mutate(
  male = Recode(sex, "'male' = 1; NA=NA; else = 0"),
  human = Recode(species, "'Human' = 1; NA=NA; else = 0"),
  maleXby = male * birth_year,
)

mod <- 'mass ~ height + human + male + birth_year + maleXby'
fit <- sem(mod, data = sw2, missing="fiml.x")
summary(fit)
```

What I want to do is plot the interaction term like a margin plot, to visualize the interaction effect. But package like library(interactions) does not work with an object of class `lavaan`. How could I visualize this? Is there a package  (like `interactions`) that makes this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fit this model using `lm()`, but I think you want to be able to use FIML estimates, yes?  In that case, you could use the `emmeans` package, which can work on `lavaan`-class objects if you have the `semTools` package loaded.

You didn't say which predictor was focal vs. moderator, but I assume you want to treat `male` as moderator because it is a grouping variable.  The example below can be adapted by switching their roles in the `pairs()` function, as well as by selecting different `birth_year` levels `at=` which to probe the effect of `male`.  When `birth_year` is the focal predictor, its linear effect will be the same regardless of which levels are chosen, so I chose the full `range()` below.

```
library(emmeans)
library(semTools)

## for ease of use, fit model using colon operator
mod <- 'mass ~ height + human + male + birth_year + male:birth_year'
fit <- sem(mod, data = sw2, missing = "fiml.x")

## calculate expected marginal means for multiple 
## levels of male (1:0) and birth_year
BYrange <- range(sw2$birth_year, na.rm = TRUE)
em.mass <- emmeans(fit, specs = ~ birth_year | male, 
                   at = list(male = 1:0, birth_year = BYrange),
                   # because SEMs can have multiple DVs:
                   lavaan.DV = "mass")
em.mass
## probe effect of year across sex
rbind(pairs(em.mass))
## plot effect of year across sex
emmip(em.mass, male ~ birth_year)   # 2 lines in same plot
emmip(em.mass, ~ birth_year | male) # in separate panels
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`> em.mass <- emmeans(fit, specs = ~ birth_year | male, 
+                    at = list(male = 1:0, birth_year = BYrange),
+                    # because SEMs can have multiple DVs:
+                    lavaan.DV = "mass")
Error in if (all(grid$.wgt.[idx] == 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: I can run your and my syntax without errors.  Maybe a version issue?  I am using R 4.2.1 with packages: semTools_0.5-6.907 emmeans_1.8.1-1    dplyr_1.0.10  car_3.1-0          carData_3.0-5   and   lavaan_0.6-12.   Perhaps my development version of semTools fixed a bug in the emmeans functionality?  `devtools::install_github("simsem/semTools/semTools")`

Comment: that worked. Thank you! The problem seems to be that I didn't have some of these updates, including the latest version of R. I'm new to R and haven't gotten into the habit of updating everything. I also seem to forget how to do it all each time.

Comment: Glad it worked!  Please don't forget to indicate if this answer was useful.