# Plot interaction effect (continuous predictor by 3-category moderator variable) in SEM with observed variables in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan, emmeans

I am estimating an SEM model that has observed variables. I want to use SEM to handle missing data using FIML. My model has an interaction term to test for moderation (continuous predictor by 3-category moderator variable). I want all lines of the interaction to appear in the same plot, so I assume I need to keep the 3-category moderator as a single variable rather than dummy code it. I get the following error when trying to estimate the model:

> Error in data[[NAMES[1L]]] * data[[NAMES[2L]]] :    non-numeric
> argument to binary operator

Here is a toy example that illustrates the issue.

```
library(lavaan)
library(car)
library(dplyr)
library(emmeans)
library(semTools)

data(starwars)

sw2 <- starwars %>% mutate(
  male = Recode(sex, "'male' = 1; NA=NA; else = 0"),
  sex2 = Recode(sex, "c('hermaphroditic','none') = 'other'"),
  human = Recode(species, "'Human' = 1; NA=NA; else = 0")
)

mod <- 'mass ~ height + human + sex2 + birth_year + sex2:birth_year'
## This is where the error occurs
fit <- sem(mod, data = sw2, missing = "fiml.x")

## calculate expected marginal means for multiple 
## levels of birth_year
BYrange <- range(sw2$birth_year, na.rm = TRUE)

## This is from previous code where 'male' was binary. 
## How would I modify the 'range' code here to allow for 3 categories
## in the 'sex2' variable?
malerange <- range(sw2$male, na.rm = TRUE) 
em.mass <- emmeans(fit, specs = ~ birth_year | male, 
                   at = list(male = 1:0, birth_year = BYrange),
                   # because SEMs can have multiple DVs:
                   lavaan.DV = "mass")
em.mass
## probe effect of birth_year across sex2
rbind(pairs(em.mass))
## plot effect of birth_year across sex2 in the same plot
emmip(em.mass, sex2 ~ birth_year)
```

Comment: Thanks to @Terrence for help with this issue when the moderator was binary. Thanks in advance, if you have any insight into how to handle this when the moderator has 3 categories.

Comment: You're welcome!  That other post is here, btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861074/plot-interaction-effect-in-sem-model-with-observed-variables-in-r

Comment: Your example is odd because `sex == "other"` occurs only when `human == 1` (see table: `table(Human = sw2$human, Sex = sw2$sex2)`). So the effect of an "other" dummy code would have to be nested under the `human` effect, which could be accomplished with a tailored model.  If this mimics your real situation, I can try to post a working answer with these data.  Otherwise, perhaps post a different example or take `human` out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multicategory grouping variables need to be represented using multiple numeric codes that you choose yourself.  This makes it impossible for `emmeans` to know when a set of (e.g.) dummy codes are actually from a single categorical variable.  The `?lavaan2emmeans` help page has an example showing the use of contrasts designed to test specific hypotheses.

But an easier route might be to specify a multigroup model. The limitation of this approach is that any cases with a missing value on the grouping variable will be deleted.

```
## remove rows with  missing sex2 to prevent
## error in emmeans() caused by lavPredict()
sw3 <- sw2[!is.na(sw2$sex2), ]

## fit model without "human" because it 
## has no variance in the "other" group
mod <- 'mass ~ height + birth_year'
fit3g <- sem(mod, data = sw3, missing = "fiml.x", group = "sex2",
             # optional: set group order to be alphabetical
             group.label = c("female","male","other"))
em3g <- emmeans(fit3g, specs = ~ birth_year | sex2,
                at = list(birth_year = 10:9),
                lavaan.DV = "mass", nesting = NULL)
rbind(pairs(em3g))
```

Like in my reply to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861074/plot-interaction-effect-in-sem-model-with-observed-variables-in-r), the slope of continuous predictor `birth_year` can be returned by choosing any `at=` values 1 unit apart.  Above, I used: `at = list(birth_year = 10:9)`, with a higher number first so that the "comparison" returns the correct sign of the slopes:

```
coef(fit3g)[paste0("mass~birth_year", c("",".g2",".g3"))]
```

Comment: Thanks once again, @Terrence. This works. However, it defeats the purpose for me to lose missing cases on the grouping variable. I was hoping FIML might be an avenue to avoid multiple imputation. It seems with interaction effects, it might actually be easier to just go with multiple imputation. Thanks again!

Comment: If you create your own contrast-coded variables to test hypotheses of interest, you can still take the FIML approach and you wouldn't need `emmeans`.

Comment: What do you mean by contrast-coded variables?

Comment: For 3 groups you can specify 3-1=2 contrasts.  e.g., one contrast could compare binary (male or female) to nonbinary (other) groups, so code those groups male=-1, female=-1, and other=+2.  Then a second contrast could compare male to female by coding male=+1 and female=-1.  Any regression textbook should provide more info.

Comment: Thanks, Terrence. I think it's a difference in how disciplines describe this. I'll check this out. Thanks!