# Change styles of interaction plot using emmeans packages

Tags: r, emmeans

I was following a great discussion plotting interactions in SEM; the original discussion is here: [Plot interaction effect in sem model with observed variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861074/plot-interaction-effect-in-sem-model-with-observed-variables-in-r)

```
library(emmeans)
library(semTools)

## for ease of use, fit model using colon operator
mod <- 'mass ~ height + human + male + birth_year + male:birth_year'
fit <- sem(mod, data = sw2, missing = "fiml.x")

## calculate expected marginal means for multiple 
## levels of male (1:0) and birth_year
BYrange <- range(sw2$birth_year, na.rm = TRUE)
em.mass <- emmeans(fit, specs = ~ birth_year | male, 
                   at = list(male = 1:0, birth_year = BYrange),
                   # because SEMs can have multiple DVs:
                   lavaan.DV = "mass")
em.mass
## probe effect of year across sex
rbind(pairs(em.mass))
## plot effect of year across sex
emmip(em.mass, male ~ birth_year)   # 2 lines in same plot
emmip(em.mass, ~ birth_year | male) # in separate panels
```

This is the original code, and it was successful to reproduce.
I just wonder how to change the style of the plot. I want to change the color to black/white, and change the labels.
I made changes like this but nothing changed.

```
emmip(em.mass, male ~ birth_year, col = c(1,1), lty= (1,5)
)
```

Does anyone have solutions? Also, I'd like to change the label of the marginal points. For example-- Not 0,1 but male and female.

Comment: perhaps the simplest thing to do would be to do `dat <- emmip(..., plotit = FALSE)` which saves everything in the plot in a data frame. Then plot those data anyway you like.

Comment: Using the function, it was successful to change the labels and colors of the plot. But it does not allow me to change the line type.. `emmip_ggplot(dat, CIs= T,   lty= c(1,5) )+scale_colour_grey(labels= c("male", "female"))+  theme_bw()`lty function does not work here

Answer (score 0):

In my initial comment, I was really trying to suggest that you get the plot data and then start from scratch to produce the plot. Here is an example

```r
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)

noise.lm = lm(noise ~ size * type, data = auto.noise)

plot.dat = emmip(noise.lm, type ~ size, plotit = FALSE)

ggplot(data = plot.dat, 
       aes_(x = ~xvar, y = ~yvar, 
            group = ~tvar, linetype = ~tvar, shape = ~tvar)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Size", y = "Marginal mean", linetype = "type", shape = "type") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I have made some changes in an upcoming version to **emmeans** and `emmip_ggplot()` in particular to increase flexibility with line types and shapes, as well as color, so that this sort of thing can be done more easily within the `emmip()` context. I also added an example of producing a black-and-white plot, which is a common need.